# Running a command in the background

Tags: linux, command-line, display

I was wondering if there is a way to execute a command to start a client in the background, with no output on the screen.

I want to run multiple clients in the background of my screen.

Thank you

Comment: Running commands in background, advanced usage: [*Difference between `nohup`, `disown` and `&`*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618).

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the screen command, which gives you more advanced options that the other commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just add an ampersand (`&`) at the end of command.

You'll also be able to redirect standard output using `>` and standard error with `2>`.

ex:

```
ls &                                 # will background the LS command (you'll have a ready prompt) but will show standard output and standard error
ls > /dev/null &                     # will do LS in background showing only standard error
ls > /dev/null 2>&1 &                # will execute the LS command discarding any output        
ls > ls_output.txt &                 # will background LS and store the output in ls_output.txt while error still on video
ls > ls_output.txt 2>ls_error.log &  # will put LS output in ls_output.txt and errors in ls_error.log
ls > ls_output_all.txt 2>&1 &        # will put both LS standard error and standard output to same output_all.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, that was where I was looking for :) works like a charm

Comment: fixed (showing only standard error)

Comment: edited again (I was missing redirection to /dev/null)

Comment: @WesleySchravendijk Don't hesitate to mark this answer as "accepted" if it helps to solve your problem please!

Comment: @DDS When answering a question that seems like it might have been answered before, please check that there are no duplicate questions on this site.